# Простое соединение CSS + JS

Tags: javascript, css

```js
function RandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)}
let root = document.querySelector(":root");
root.style.setProperty("--random", RandomInt(2, 4));
let time = RandomInt(6, 18);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  overflow: hidden}

:root {
  --visota: 100vh;
  --visota_menu: 20vh;
  --visota_real: calc(var(--visota) - var(--visota_menu));
  --random}

@keyframes a_Down {
  from {
    transform-origin: center bottom}
  75% {
    transform: translate3d(0px, var(--visota_real), 0px) 
               rotateX(calc(var(--random, 1) * 360deg)) 
               rotateY(calc(var(--random, 1) * 360deg)) 
               rotateZ(calc(var(--random, 1) * 180deg)) 
      }
                   }
```

```html
<div id="World" onmouseenter="Animatecss('World', 'a_Down', 100, time*1000)"> Hello, World!</div>
```

там есть CSS-переменная `--random`. Она определяет вращение по любой оси  X и Y и Z. rotateY(calc(var(--random, 18) * 1deg));

18 -- с потолка, на случай не определения --random.
Как придать переменной --random CЛУЧАЙНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ?
Т.е. вращение  по оси X и Y и Z случайное ?
Я просто слышал, что это можно сделать только через JS .
Можно ли обойтись без JS ? И как связать JS и CSS ?

Ответ: я сделал ошибку, пытаясь присвоить CCS-переменной "--random" случайное значение, а затем наоборот, брать из нее же это же значение и присваивать его JS-переменной rand. Это лишнее. Одинаковое значение в обоих переменных вызовет одинаковую скорость вращение, т.е. одинаковое число оборотов в секунду.
Это делается так:

let rand2 = getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue("--random");

Но это лишнее, и не обязательно. Просто разделяем их на разные случайные значения.

---

P.S. коллеги, что-то сломалось. Анимация не работает. Но Есть рабочий пример на [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/oblominsk/pen/MWQQMRo). Библиотеки JS доступны. Интересно, где ошибка ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370741/how-do-i-edit-a-css-variable-using-js

Comment: Спасибо что подметили, не перенёс скрипты.

Comment: Он работает точно так же, как на codepen, откуда я его и скопировал.

Comment: Нажмите кнопку "править" и отредактируйте, это ваш вопрос. К тому же сниппет (то место где код с возможность его воспроизвести) можно развернуть на весь экран.

Comment: я не понимаю, что делать с этим Ctrl+K . Я не могу отредактировать первое сообщение.  На https://codepen.io/oblominsk/pen/MWQQMRo ---- все работает.  Мой код можно упростить и получить случайные переменные из JS в CSS. Благодарность за помощь https://forum.vivaldi.net/user/luetage

Comment: сейчас поворот  по оси Y не случайный , а ровно 18 градусов, т.к.  --random  не определена.

Comment: Почитайте [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: я убрал округление входных данных. Теперь MIN и MAX могут только целые. Самое смешное, что этот код полностью скопировал с developers.mozilla.org . Но этот сайт его не понимает :).

Comment: я отремонтировал наконец-то  свой codepen.io/ -- можно смотреть выше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передавайте не в `:root`, а напрямую элементу.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.random-deg');

setInterval(function() {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
  el.style.setProperty('--rotate', rand);
  console.clear();
  console.log(`random ${rand}deg`);
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.random-deg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 60px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  transition: transform ease .2s;
  transform: rotate(calc(var(--rotate, 18) * 1deg));
}
```

```html
<div class="random-deg"></div>
```

---

Если всё же нужен `:root`, то к нему обращаемся через `document.documentElement`

```js
const root = document.documentElement;

setInterval(function() {
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
  root.style.setProperty('--rotate', rand);
  console.clear();
  console.log(`random ${rand}deg`);
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

:root {
  --rotate: 0;
}

.random-deg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 60px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  transition: transform ease .2s;
  transform: rotate(calc(var(--rotate, 18) * 1deg));
}
```

```html
<div class="random-deg"></div>
```

Comment: хороший пример. 
интересно. Я где-то читал , что без перезагрузки страницы Math.random() не может изменяться.
А где вывод строки с градусами ?

Comment: @seregada, по сути да, не может, если вызвать его единожды, но мы его выполняем в цикле по таймеру, он просто "воспроизводится" снова и перезаписывает старое значение. `console.clear()` - очищает консоль, а `console.log()` выводит.

Comment: очень хорошо, обращение к :root -- мне просто показали  эту возможность. Я ее использовал , как единственную. Я тоже этого не понимаю, но работает ! Буду разбираться !  Особенно спасибо за console.log()  -- мне тоже не понятно как посмотреть значение переменной.
De.Minov ,  может  , ты сможешь отредактировать мой вопрос, а то он недоделан сейчас.

Comment: @seregada, отредактируйте самостоятельно, если что-то будет не так, постараюсь помочь в редактирование.

Comment: по вашим примерам интересно. Но у меня нет класса, а есть keyframes . Как передать в него ?  Как передать значение --random  напрямую без класса или  keyframes ? Я вижу, что передавать напрямую элементу не короче, чем через :Root. Тем более, в :Root объявляются и другие переменные.

Comment: В случае с `@keyframes` скорее всего лучше объявлять (и переназначать) переменную наверное в `:root`, либо `html` или `body`. Честно говоря, не могу сказать точно, т.к. такой задачи на моей практики не было.