# Не работает в событиях CSS переменные или расчеты

Tags: javascript, css

Вопрос связан с [Простое соединение CSS + JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1426847/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-css-js)

Вот рабочий пример: https://codepen.io/oblominsk/pen/MWQQMRo

```js
function RandomInt(min, max) {
 min = Math.ceil(min);
 max = Math.floor(max);
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
let root = document.querySelector(":root");
root.style.setProperty("--random", RandomInt(1, 4));
```

```css
body {
 font-family: system-ui;
 background: #f06d06;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 100px;
     }
:root {
 --visota: 100vh;
 --visota_menu: 120px;
 --visota_real: calc(var(--visota) - var(--visota_menu));
 --random
      }
@keyframes a_Down {
 0% {transform-origin: center bottom}
 75% {transform: perspective(500px) 
                 translate3d(0px, var(--visota_real), 0px)
                 rotateX(calc(var(--random, 1) * 180deg))
                 rotateY(calc(var(--random, 1) * 360deg))
                 rotateZ(calc(var(--random, 1) * 180deg)) 
     }
                  }
```

```html
<div id="World" style="position: relative" onmouseenter="AnimateCss('World', 'a_Down', 0, 6000); return false"> Hello, World!</div>
```

```
:root {
--random;
--random_ms: calc(3 *6000)}
```

там есть часть кода HTML, все работает.

```
<div id="World" style="position: relative" 
onmouseenter="AnimateCss('World', 'a_Down', 0, 6000); return false">
 Hello, World!</div>
```

*(ну, редактор у вас , жесть. А зачем кнопка HTML ?)*

Здесь расписан внутренний стиль. Я смог (мне помогли) связать CSS и JS. Очень полезная вещь. Задавал этот вопрос разным людям, настоящие гуру всей этой разметки, но ответить не могут :). Только один, настоящий профи. В тех 3 строках все есть.

Но решил я пойти еще дальше -- всунуть переменную CSS везде , где можно.
И в этом же примере она не работает. Значит, не все связи установлены. Не вся мощь CSS задействована.
Переменная var(--random,1) прекрасно работает в

```
transform: ... rotateX(calc(var(--random, 1) * 360deg))
```

В примере выше, число 6000 указывает время падения объекта id="World". Хотелось бы  и туда ее всунуть -- в событие анимации, вместо 6000.
Но **не работает**
Т.е. 3 варианта (вместо 6000):

```
1. calc(var(--random,1) * 6000) -- расчет с переменной
2. calc(3 * 6000) -- расчет без переменной
3. var(--random_ms,1) -- переменная без расчетов
```

ни один не работает. Странно, вроде бы эта переменная видна из JS в CSS .
Думаю, что видимость CSS в HTML не подвергается сомнению :)
Все JS подключены.
Я даже толком не знаю, откуда взялась эта AnimateCss() -- что это JS или CSS ?
Первая ссылка поиске https://animate.style показывает , что вроде бы мы нашли ее. Но там даже толком синтаксис нигде не описан. Откуда взялась эта AnimateCss() ?

**Вопрос:** почему внутри AnimateCss() не работают переменные и расчеты calc() ?

Как я не проверил ? Внутри внутри AnimateCss() прекрасно работают расчеты без calc()

Comment: скорее всего, ответ знает коллега из предыдущего моего вопроса. Но он только по-английски. И не отвечает

Comment: Хотелось бы услышать коллегу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/221218/de-minov -- очень полезные ответы . Настоящие инструкции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

на кодпэне прикреплен min.js а в нём и задана AnimateCss функция.

вот ссылка вроде на тот самый js: https://seregasmyfavoritesites.on.drv.tw/Site/CSS-JS/www.min.js

p.s. можно легко обойтись без него, дописав примерно такой css:

```
#World:hover{animation: a_Down 6000ms 500ms both;}
```

правда в этом случае... как только вращающийся блок улетит из под мыши анимация сбросится. для избежания этого `div#World` обернул в `div#x` :

```js
function RandomInt(min, max) {
 min = Math.ceil(min);
 max = Math.floor(max);
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
let root = document.querySelector(":root");
root.style.setProperty("--random", RandomInt(1, 4));
```

```css
body {
 font-family: system-ui;
 background: #f06d06;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 100px;
     }
:root {
 --visota: 100vh;
 --visota_menu: 120px;
 --visota_real: calc(var(--visota) - var(--visota_menu));
 --random
      }
@keyframes a_Down {
 0% {transform-origin: center bottom}
 75% {transform: perspective(500px) 
      translate3d(0px, var(--visota_real), 0px)
      rotateX(calc(var(--random, 1) * 180deg))
      rotateY(calc(var(--random, 1) * 360deg))
      rotateZ(calc(var(--random, 1) * 180deg)) 
     }
}
#x:hover > #World{animation: a_Down 6000ms 500ms both;}
```

```html
<div id='x'><div id="World" style="position: relative"> Hello, World!</div></div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139828/discussion-on-answer-by-puffleeck-----css---).